# Is the Schroedinger picture outside the contemporary maintstream?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-interpretations, superposition

By the Schroedinger picture, I mean the notion that atoms exist in a superposition of states, as opposed to the Copenhagen picture, which I understand to mean that in a system of atoms, all the atoms are in discrete eigenstates and jump instantaneously from one state to another with the emission and absorption of photons. If I follow what I've called the Schroedinger picture, am I outside of standard physics (and therefore outside the parameters of this discussion group?

For example: let us consider a system of hydrogen atoms where 90% of them are in the ground state and 10% are in the 2s or 2p state (as described by the Copenhagen picture.) Am I justified as looking at the same system as though each atom was in a superposition of two states, 90% ground level and 10% excited state? Or does it put me outside the mainstream for me to take that point of view?

And do the two points of view lead to different physics? Can we say conclusively that one or the other is correct?

Comment: Note: this question is actually about thermal states and density matrices. In other questions, the OP has been told that a thermal state is best described by a density matrix, and _not_ as a superposition. This is perfectly standard and mainstream, but nobody really motivated it for him.

Comment: Marty, if you want more direct answers, I would directly ask "how can we tell apart the superposition picture and the density matrix picture?" Otherwise you're only going to get people saying "Yes, Schrodinger is mainstream."

Comment: I think it is a justified and interesting question. Whether and how many individual atoms with two energy states are in pure superposition states when the system is at elevated temperature and what impact, if any, this has on the measured probabilities seems not yet to have been answered below.

Comment: Please do not edit questions needlessly just to bump them. If you want to draw attention to an old question, please either do a substatinal edit adding actual information or offer a bounty.

Answer (score 2):

By "the Copenhagen version" you seem to have some kind of Bohr model picture in mind, in which there is no such thing as quantum superposition(please correct me if I am wrong), in which case it is this Copenhagen picture that is outside mainstream physics. Superposition is a phenomenon which has, at this point, been experimentally verified countless times.

It is, however, important to note that a collection of atoms in which 90% are in one state and 10% are in another is a very different state to one in in which all the atoms are in a 90%-10% superposition. The latter would be a pure state while the former would be a [mixed state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix#Pure_and_mixed_states) of the system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am quite sure you are using the incorrect  (or non-standard) definition of pure vs. mixed states. I believe both of my examples would be considered pure states. The real question is: if you are quite certain they are different states, then how would you tell them apart? and which one more accurately describes a rarefied hydorgen gas at 7000 degrees Kelvin?

Comment: While technically there does exist a pure state with a 90%-10% mixture of particles (not in superposition) in it, unless you know which particle you are looking at when take a measurement, it will look like a mixed state. Yes the states are experimentally distinguishable; if you conduct an interference experiment between the 2 states you will observe interference when the particles are in superposition and will not when they are not.

Comment: If what you are actually interested in what happens to gas at some finite temperature then the answer is that you will then definitely have a mixed state that is more complicated than either possibility stated here.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I should say that you are not using "Schrodinger" and "Copenhagen" pictures in a way that I as a physicist recognize as mainstream. I would regard "Schrodinger picture" as just being one way of organizing time-dependence (as opposed to "Heisenberg") and the "Copenhagen interpretation" (not "picture") as being related to wavefunction collapse upon measurement.

However, I can answer the question of whether we can treat superpositions as ensembles or not. The answer is no, as I will argue from a quantum information perspective. Suppose we start with many atoms/qubits, which are all in a $| 0 \rangle + | 1 \rangle$ state. I then apply a rotation by $\phi$ about the Z axis of the Bloch sphere, and my state will be:

$$
\left( | 0 \rangle + e^{i \phi} |1 \rangle \right)^{\otimes N}
$$

Then I perform a Hadamard transform and measure. I will measure the state $|0 \rangle$ in each qubit with probability $\cos^2 \phi/2$.

Or, I could have started with half my atoms in $| 0 \rangle$ and half in $| 1 \rangle$. Under the transforms I said before, the Z-rotation no longer matters--it adds a trivial phase to each individual wavefunction. Therefore the Hadamard transform will simply map both of them to equal superpositions (population-wise) of $| 0 \rangle$ and $| 1 \rangle$, and I measure $|0 \rangle$ with probability $1/2$ for all of them. Since one of these measurement procedures is sensitive to the rotation, and one is not, I can clearly tell the difference between the two. This is precisely how Ramsey interferometry works, and so is the basis of e.g. atomic clock timekeeping, atomic magnetometry, atomic gravimetry, and other quantum measurement schemes.

Comment: So which of my two pictures more accurately describes a rarefied gas of monatomic hydrogen at 7000 degrees Kelvin?

Comment: A little of both. A quantum system in temperature equilibrium has a density matrix given by $\exp (- \beta H )$ where $\beta$ is inverse temperature and $H$ is the Hamiltonian operator. If an atom was in one of a few different states, probabilistically, that would be a purely diagonal matrix. Superpositions show up as off-diagonal elements (coherences) of the density matrix. It also depends on what you count as the system and what you count as the thermal bath -- generally you only get mixed states if you discard some information somewhere.

Comment: So I've proposed a thermal system which is essentially a two-state system, if we can assume that we're not too interested in distinguishing the 2p and 2s states (consider all them to be "the exited state" and that the temperature is such that the 3s, 3p etc. states are negligibly populated). Can you write the density matrix?

Comment: In general? Yes, just by putting that exponential for a two-by-two matrix into Mathematica (or being more cleverly algebraic). The tricky bit of that is that the Hamiltonian ought to include a coupling between the two states (because presumably they're both exposed to 7000K black body radiation).  That gives you off-diagonal terms, but to tell you how large they are I'd have to actually carry out the integral over the radiation field, which isn't something I can just dash off here.

Comment: Look: you are giving me the most informative, responsive answers that I can hope to get on this site but we are still not there. Suppose there is no black-body radiation, and no interaction with radiation. From a purely mechanical standpoint, there must still be a thermal equilibrium of the states. Does that simplify things enough to write the matrix explicitly? (And...is it a 2x2 matrix, or a 100x100 matrix depending on how many hydrogen atoms there are? I don't know the answer to that.)

Comment: If you remove the EM field entirely, then you would get a diagonal matrix in the atomic-states basis, so you would have your ensemble picture, I think. But it's a very, very nonphysical way to look at it--in the real world, the EM field is always there. Anyway, it's 2x2 if it's one atom, strictly speaking it's $2^{2N} \times 2^{2N}$ for $N$ atoms -- but this takes full account of the entire Hilbert space, including many entangled states, which are not usually relevant in thermal states.

Comment: Okay, let's interpret that diagonal matrix. I think you are saying that without the interaction with the external field, in the simplified case where the atoms are only interacting mechanically, that each one of them would be in one of the eigenstates...ground state or excited...and that essentially none of them would be in a superposition. Is that what it means to have a diagonal matrix? (Because I think physically it's the wrong answer.)

Comment: @MartyGreen Yes, but you need to remember what it means to have a defined temperature in a canonical ensemble (which is what I've written). It implies that there's a large reservoir of energy which is exchanged with the system until the system comes to equilibrium. This amounts to a constant measurement of, and projection onto, energy eigenstates of the system. Since the reservoir is large enough to "forget" the measured state, we end up with a probabilistic mix of energy eigenstates. I recommend Pathria's book for statistical mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

The usual "Schroedinger picture" is only one way to formulate the standard "Copenhagen version" of quantum mechanics just like the "Heisenberg picture" or the Dirac picture. They are mathematically equivalent. As far as I know, there exists no "Copenhagen picture" as opposed to the Schroedinger picture. People talk about the "Copenhagen interpretation" of quantum mechanics which is the interpretation mostly propagated and assumed in textbooks. But different interpretations usually make the same predictions based on equivalent mathematics. Also in pictures other than the Schroedinger picture atoms can exist in a superposition of eigenstates. The quantum mechanics is exactly the same. When you prepare a system of hydrogen atoms 90% in the ground state and 10% in the 2s or any other definite state, this is not equivalent to a system of hydrogen atoms each prepared in a superposition of 90% probability of the 1s eigenstate and 10% probability in the other specific excited state. All pictures of standard quantum mechanics would give you this same answer.

Comment: You are not answering my question. Let's "prepare" an ensemble of hydrogen atoms by reducing the pressure sufficiently so that the monatomic state is thermodynamically favored over the diatomic state (as it is in outer space) and then raising the temperature so that the excited states becom populated to the extent of 10%. I believe in the Copenhagen formulation, we would say that 90% of the atoms are in the ground state and 10% in the excited state. But the question is: can you prove that it's not the other way....that all the atoms are in a superposition 90-10 of both states???

Comment: @ Marty - Thank you for clarifying your question, which is really intriguing. If you "prepare" your H-atom system by raising the temperature so that 90% of the atoms are in the ground state and practically 10% are in the next higher state (you cannot exclude even higher states here) you have a statistical ensemble with, in essence, "classical" probabilities of the two different states. Quantum mechanically you have a "mixed state" which in standard quantum mechanical statistics formally has to be described by a density matrix.

Comment: Yes, you're now onside. True, there are higher states, but for simplicity's sake we can arrange so that they are negligible...if not at the 90-10 level, then at the 99-1 level. At some point we can treat it for simplicity as a two-state system. I still want to know if individual atoms within that system are more likely to be in a pure state (either the ground or excited states) or whether they would tend to all more or less be in a superposition. I don't think that talking about a "mixed state" answers that question, and I can't see how quantum mechanics precludes me from asking that question.

Comment: @ Marty - In contrast, when you prepare all your atoms in a 90-10% superposition of the two states, you have a "pure state" of the system, that means it has one wave function or vector in Hilbert space where these probabilities are quantum mechanical probabilities for each atom to be in the lower or upper state. This is, I think, the standard quantum mechanics answer to your question. Your question is definitely justified. I wonder whether it has ever been checked expetimentally.  Maybe a good system to do so would be spin 1/2 particles with two energy states in a magnetic field.

Comment: @ Marty - Whether the individual atoms in such a situation might themselves be in pure superposition of states and what effect this would have on the probabilities of the "mixed state" statistical ensemble is a really good question. Perhaps one of the theory experts could give us an answer on this. Maybe this could be investigated with a real 2-level system with spin 1/2  atoms with magnetic dipoles  in a magnetic field and Stern-Gerlach analyzers.

Comment: I don't like depending on the authority of experts. Things have to make sense. And...by the way...for a a system of spin 1/2 atoms in a magnetic field, there's no doubt that each atom is most likely in a superposition state. It makes no physical sense to imagine them being aligned either spin-up or spin-down with nothing in between.